# UPDATE de algunos datos SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

AYUDAA

Quiero hacer un UPDATE a una tabla para actualizar algunos códigos de cliente que están mal, mi pregunta es si en un UPDATE puedo colocar subconsultas en el SET, osea asi:

`UPDATE tabla1 SET codigo=(select codigo from codigos c where c.tipo=1) WHERE TipoCodigo in (1,2,3)`

Quiero si esta forma es validar para implementarlo en mi query

Comment: No es recomendable, porque la subconsulta puede traer mas es un registro

Comment: La respuesta más simple es: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Piensa que cuando hagas la update, si no tienes claro el resultado, luego no hay vuelta atrás. Pierde un poco de tiempo en preparar un escenario completo y seguro que obtienes una buena respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con UPDATE SELECT. En este método la tabla que se va a actualizar se unirá a la segunda tabla que contiene nuevos valores:

He creado dos variables tipo tabla, una con códigos y otra personas para simular la actualización de los datos.

```
    DECLARE @TABLA_CODIGO AS TABLE (id int identity,tipoCodigo int,codigo varchar(5))
INSERT INTO @TABLA_CODIGO (tipoCodigo,codigo)
values (1,'A21'),(2,'B22'),(3,'C23'),(4,'C24')
SELECT * FROM @TABLA_CODIGO

DECLARE @TABLA_PERSONAS AS TABLE (id int identity,nombre varchar(50),codigo varchar(5),tipoCodigo int)
INSERT INTO @TABLA_PERSONAS (nombre,codigo,tipoCodigo)
values ('Erick','00001',1),('MANUEL','00002',2),('JUAN','00003',3),('MIGUEL','00004',4)
SELECT * FROM @TABLA_PERSONAS

UPDATE @TABLA_PERSONAS SET codigo = c.codigo
FROM @TABLA_PERSONAS p, @TABLA_CODIGO c
WHERE p.tipoCodigo in (1,2,3) AND c.tipoCodigo =1

SELECT * FROM @TABLA_PERSONAS
```

El resultado:

```
id          tipoCodigo  codigo
----------- ----------- ------
1           1           A21
2           2           B22
3           3           C23
4           4           C24

id          nombre                                             codigo tipoCodigo
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ------ -----------
1           Erick                                              00001  1
2           MANUEL                                             00002  2
3           JUAN                                               00003  3
4           MIGUEL                                             00004  4


(3 filas afectadas)

id          nombre                                             codigo tipoCodigo
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ------ -----------
1           Erick                                              A21    1
2           MANUEL                                             A21    2
3           JUAN                                               A21    3
4           MIGUEL                                             00004  4
```